# Record more events with procmon

Tags: batch-file, monitoring

'Process Monitor' has a max history depth of 199 million events. I need to record about 10 times this. I don't mind if the data is split, e.g. a new data set for every hour. Anyone know how to do it? I'm guessing a batch file, with backing files going to sequentially named folders. Is there a way of detecting once Process Monitor has filled its history depth to kill it, or do I just need to sleep?

Comment: You need to record about 2 billion events?  From one server?  Really?  This makes me think that whatever you're trying to do, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I need to analyze an event that only happens once a night on a server under load

Comment: For the record, here's what I used:@echo off

set PM=C:\ProcessMonitor\Procmon.exe

:loop

rem create dir name
set T=%time:~0,5%
set dir=%date:/=-% %T::=-%

rem create dir
mkdir "z:\%dir%\"

rem start recording to dir
start %PM% /backingfile "z:\%dir%\procmon" /Quiet /Minimized

rem sleep 10 minutes
sleep 600

rem kill procmon
%PM% /terminate

rem repeat
goto loop

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're going to have to script it.  I've done some similar work with Procmon like this before, but my aim was nothing like to capture billions of events. Nevertheless, this should help you, unless you needed someone to write the script for you:

Create a VBscript that runs every 5 minutes. Task Scheduler can help you with that.

If this is the first time the script has run, then start Procmon like so:

```
objShell.Run "Cmd /C " & PRM_ProcMonExe & " /quiet /minimized /AcceptEula /backingfile " & PRM_PMLDir & "Procmon" & subDir & ".pml"
```

Then on subsequent runs of the script, measure the total size of all the *.pml files in the subDir.

```
If ProcMonTriggered = True And ProcMonTerminated = False Then
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(PRM_PMLDir)
    Set objFiles = objFolder.Files
    For Each objItem In objFiles
        If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objItem.Name)) = "PML" Then
            totalPMLSize = totalPMLSize + objItem.Size
        End If
    Next
    If totalPMLSize > (PRM_PMLMaxSize * 1073741824) Then
        NQExt.CreateEvent PRM_TriggeredSev, "ProcMon Terminated", "AKP_NULL", gstrEventTarget, 0.0, "Process Monitor was terminated because the PML file reached the limit of " & PRM_PMLMaxSize & "GB." & vbCrlf & "Process Monitor cannot be triggered again until this script is re-deployed." & vbCrlf & "Please see KB " & PRM_KBArticle, "", 0, 0
        Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        objShell.Run "Cmd /C " & PRM_ProcMonExe & " /AcceptEula /terminate"         
    End If
    If isObject(objFiles) Then Set objFiles = Nothing
    If isObject(objFolder) Then Set objFolder = Nothing
    If isObject(objShell) Then Set objShell = Nothing
    If isObject(objFSO) Then Set objFSO = Nothing
    ProcMonTerminated = True
End If
```

That isn't specifically tailored to your situation. You'll have to tweak it. That's something I wrote a long time ago for a slightly different purpose. What you want to do is if the size of all the *.pml files in the subdirectory added together has not increased since the last time the script ran... then you know it's time to terminate Procmon and start a new instance.

The point is that you have to terminate Procmon gracefully with the /terminate parameter, not just kill the process, or else the log will be corrupt and unreadable.

Then start a new instance of procmon in a new subDir. Creativity will have you creating subdirectories with incremental names like subdir1, subdir2, subdir3, etc.

Edit: Also, I've never run Procmon to 200 million events before, so I don't know if it just sits there and does nothing after reaching 199 million, or if it completely shuts down.  If the latter is the case, then your job is easier.  Just check if Procmon.exe is still running.  If it's not, then  you know it's time to fire it up again under a new subdirectory.

Edit: Yeah I think it just starts rolling once it hits the history depth... so do the file size thing.